# Background Gradient in Fabric.js

Tags: html, fabricjs

Using Fabric.js, is it possible to set the background to a gradient? For example something like:

http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-linear-gradients/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you could add a rectangle with a gradient as soon as the canvas is initialized. Set the height and width of the rectangle to the height and width of the canvas. starting from (x,y)->(0,0)

```
var rect = new fabric.Rect({
  left: 0,
  top: 0,
  width: 1200,
  height: 1200
});


rect.setGradient('fill', {
  x1: 0,
  y1: rect.height,
  x2: rect.width,
  y2: rect.height,
  colorStops: {
    0: "red",
    1: "blue"
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently, Fabric.js (version 1.5.0 as of this writing) only allows for background images and background colors. To get the effect you want, you either need to set the fill of a rectangle object (as melwyn pawar describes above) and disable the controls (don't want to accidentally select the background), or you need to create an image file with the gradient you want and set it to the canvas background:

```
var imgUrl = "/path/to/image/file";  
var canvasCenter = canvas.getCenter();
fabric.Image.fromURL(imgUrl, function(oImg) {
      oImg.set({
        opacity: 1, 
        left: canvasCenter.left,
        top: canvasCenter.top,
        originX: "center", 
        originY: "center"
      });
       oImg.scaleToWidth(canvas.width);  
      }
      canvas.setBackgroundImage(oImg);
      canvas.renderAll();//you won't see it otherwise
  });
```

You can use any image creation/editing software to create the actual image.

Hopefully, future versions of Fabric.js will allow us to set the background to a gradient.

Answer (score 1):

I leave an example that shows how it can be done with the 'toLive' function of the gradient.

```js
// Do some initializing stuff
fabric.Object.prototype.set({
    transparentCorners: false,
    cornerColor: 'rgba(102,153,255,0.5)',
    cornerSize: 12,
    padding: 5
});

// initialize fabric canvas and assign to global windows object for debug
var canvas = window._canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

    
var grad = new fabric.Gradient({
    type: 'linear',
    coords: {
        x1: 0,
    y1: 0,
    x2: canvas.width,
    y2: canvas.height,
    },
    colorStops: [
    {
        color: 'rgb(166,111,213)',
        offset: 0,
    },
    {
        color: 'rgba(106, 72, 215, 0.5)',
        offset: 0.5,
    },
    {    
        color: '#200772',
        offset: 1,
    }
    ]});
    canvas.backgroundColor =    grad.toLive(canvas.contextContainer);
    canvas.renderAll();
```

```css
canvas {
    border: 1px solid #999;
}
button {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.js"></script>

<canvas id="c" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `fabric.Gradient` method which allow both linear and radial gradient.

refernce-> http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Gradient.html#initialize

```js
// Do some initializing stuff
fabric.Object.prototype.set({
    transparentCorners: false,
    cornerColor: 'rgba(102,153,255,0.5)',
    cornerSize: 12,
    padding: 5
});

// initialize fabric canvas and assign to global windows object for debug
var canvas = window._canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');    
var a_width = 400
var a_height = 400
var artboard = new fabric.Rect({
  left: this.canvas.get('width') / 2 - a_width / 2,
  top: this.canvas.get('height') / 2 - a_height / 2,
  width: a_width,
  height: a_height,
  absolutePositioned: true,
  fill: '#FFF',
  hasControls: true,
  typeThing: 'none',
  transparentCorners: false,
  borderColor: '#0E98FC',
  cornerColor: '#0E98FC',
  cursorWidth: 1,
  selectable: false,
  cursorDuration: 1,
  cursorDelay: 250,
  id: 'artboard',
})

// Clip canvas to the artboard
this.canvas.clipPath = artboard
this.canvas.renderAll()
    
var color = new fabric.Gradient({
type: 'linear',
gradientUnits: 'pixels', // or 'percentage'
coords: { x1: 0, y1: -a_height/2, x2: a_width, y2: a_height },
colorStops:[
  { offset: 0, color: '#FFE53B' },
  { offset: .74, color: '#FF2525'},
]
})

artboard.set('fill', color)
this.canvas.add(artboard)
this.canvas.renderAll()
```

```css
canvas {
    border: 1px solid #999;
}
button {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.js"></script>

<canvas id="c" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```